# footer sum data canot sum all data in serverside datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables, codeigniter-3

i have a model like here

https://pastebin.com/HLNQZgkg

```
public function data_json_judulbuku() {
    error_reporting(-1);
    if( isset($_GET['id']) ){
        $id = $_GET['id'];
    }else{
        $id = '';
    }
```

and javascript to access datatable 
https://pastebin.com/f2NrFbBr
i canot sum all data in datatables, the sum just page listed 
[result footer sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSLyA.png)

total value must 135 and curent page 15 but on display total 15 and curent page 15

Comment: because you are using serverside datatable, and meaning it will only load data for 1 page at a time, when you click pagination it will call ajax and load another data for you. So, how can you assume that sum should display for all data?. If you want to handle then you have to calculate sum server side.

Comment: i was sum all data in iSum, and i dont know how to get the Json ISum, can you help me?